The additional fields in the Additional Information section of the Resource screen are displayed duplicated
I am currently working on ckan version 2.10.3 and deployed to a docker.
I am building an extension plugin and adding fields to the additional information on the resource screen.
When translating the field name added by i18n, the field before and after translation are duplicated.
During the investigation, we found that the process to add items (before_resource_show) is called twice. *See the relevant source below
Is this behavior the expected specification or a bug?
・Relevant source
https://github.com/c-3lab/ckanext-feedback/blob/main/ckanext/feedback/plugin.py#L379
Image showing the issue
Debugging before_resource_show. I inserted a debug log in the following location and expected it to be called only once, but I found the above behavior.
https://github.com/c-3lab/ckanext-feedback/blob/main/ckanext/feedback/plugin.py#L383
